# generate a unique integer ID from multiple columns of a SQL table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, uniqueidentifier, netezza

I need to generate a new column in a table in a sql database.

the given table is:

```
id1     value1    value2    value3    value4
9465    387        801      1990        20
```

All columns are integer. value1 and value2 are always 3 digits, value3 are year value, value4 is not more than 3 digits.

I need to generate a value by combining value1 to value4, suppose that it is called "**value_combine**". The "value_combine" should be unique. For example, given the different combinations of value1 to value4,  the "**value_combine**" should also be different.

And then, the "**value_combine**" is combined with id1 such that the new value (we call it final_id) should be unique.

For example, given different combinations of id1 and value_combine, the **final_id** should also be different.

The **final_id** can be used to identify each unique combination of id1 and value1-4.

The **final_id** **MUST** be integer and all values should have the **same** **length** of digits, such as 6, 7 or 8 digits.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is something called the pigeon-hole principle that says that this cannot be done reliably:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle.

Comment: Can you possibly add a sample that illustrates your desired output?

Comment: I agree with Gordon. A `bigint` might be large enough to accommodate this kind of scheme (depending on the range of `id1`) but an `int` is not. I'm curious, though: why do you need to do this? It seems like an odd set of requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but sounds like a `DENSE_RANK()` would do:

```
SELECT id1,value1,value2,value3,value4
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY id1,value1,value2,value3,value4)+100000 AS final_ID
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: If value1-4 are same but id1 is different, the value_combine will be same if we use ROW_NUMBER(). thanks !

Comment: @GoatCO . . . I actually think you mean `dense_rank()` and the columns in the `partition by` should all be in the `order by`.  I'm still not sure if this really answers the OPs question, but it would at least provide a unique number for each combination.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Indeed, thanks, brain has left the building. Regardless, I seem to have missed what the OP is after anyway.